# SSH with rpi and Xbox Controller

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi3, putty, xbox360

So I am trying to SSH into my rpi3 and take input from an Xbox 360 controller plugged into my PC. But the it doesn't read the inputs from my controller when it is plugged into my PC. The code runs fine when everything is plugged into the pi. I am relatively new to this and am using PuTTY to SSH. Am I missing a setting or something? Or is what I am trying to do not possible.

Comment: SSH opens a text window where you type shell commands that run on the remote system.  I could see this sort-of working if you had an app running on the PC to use the xbox controller for an on-screen keyboard, but why would you want to?

Comment: It sounds like you want some sort of linux-to-PC controller sharing application where something runs on the rpi to connect to the PC which runs something to share the controller input?  That doesn't sound like SSH = SecureSHell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).